# How to print line by date range update

Tags: python, file

***Question UPDATE:***
I solved this problem by radar answer.
Question is how i can print something if i have 2 or more same dates in file, how i can compare line with line after?

*File update:*

```
25/12/2015|5940.0
25/12/2015|5720.0
25/12/2015|8404.0
26/12/2015|9229.0
27/12/2015|8380.0
27/12/2015|6998.5
27/12/2015|10667.0
28/12/2015|8720.0
```

***END OF QUESTION UPDATE!***

My program must print all lines in the range of my dates.
My file looks like this:

```
24/12/2015|5940.0
25/12/2015|5720.0
26/12/2015|8404.0
27/12/2015|9229.0
28/12/2015|8380.0
29/12/2015|6998.5
30/12/2015|10667.0
31/12/2015|8720.0
```

The first date is 28/12/2015, and the end date is 30/12/2015.

Expected:

```
28/12/2015 ---> 8380.0
29/12/2015 ---> 6998.5
30/12/2015 ---> 10667.0
```

Also in my file there will be same dates.
I heard I can use some python function for comparing the dates and print it , but I couldn't find it.

Comment: You'll need to use [`datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) to convert a string to a date object that you can compare.

Comment: Use `time.strptime(dateAsString, "%d/%m/%Y")` to covert,  then `date1 <date2` to compare.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `strptime` to convert string to datetime and use `csv` module to read the file data

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

start = datetime(2015, 12, 28)
end   = datetime(2015, 12, 30)

with open("data.txt", "r") as f:
   r = csv.reader(f,delimiter ="|")


   for line in r:
      lineDate = datetime.strptime(line[0],"%d/%m/%Y")
      if start <= lineDate <=end :
         print("{0} ---> {1}".format(*line)
```

Comment: Some suggestions. 1) if you're setting the search start/end dates, you can use for eg: `start = datetime(2015, 12, 28)` instead of using `date.strptime`, 2) when comparing you can use the fact that Python allows operator chaining so you can use `if start <= lineDate <= end`, and 3) you can make full use of `str.format` by using `print('{0} ---> {1}'.format(*line)`

Comment: @Jon Clements, thanks for the suggestions, quite helpful

Comment: Feel free to use those (if you wish) to update your answer - could well be useful to others in future - who knows :)

Comment: I updated question, could you help me for this little problem ?

Comment: @XpreSS, if there are multiple dates, do you want to print only the first date ?

Comment: yes and sum of all my prices in that date.Program must do it , but i gave here simplier example

Comment: @XpreSS, is the data in the file sorted by date, then you can remember prev date and compare the current date with prev,if it is same, u can sum up the value else print out.

Comment: @XpreSS, also it would be better to ask as a new question, as it gets noticed and you get a anwer

Comment: Dates will be always sorted

Answer (score 0):

I think you know how to read from file process but the main issue is how to convert string to dates and compare them,so here is how to compare strings as dates using [strptime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) :

```
In [1]: import datetime

In [2]: my_date = datetime.datetime.strptime("24/12/2015","%d/%m/%Y") #string_to_date

In [3]: my_date
Out[3]: datetime.datetime(2015, 12, 24, 0, 0)

In [4]: my_date_2 = datetime.datetime.strptime("28/12/2015","%d/%m/%Y")

In [5]: my_date < my_date_2 
Out[5]: True
```